# How to ensure EC2 -> S3 Sync becomes (nearly) atomic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If I run a EC2 Spot Instance, this instance can be terminated at any moment.  To save date I sync entire `directory A (which contains file B and C)` and seperate `file D` via `aws s3 sync`.

**What happens if an instance is interrupted during an `aws sync s3`?**

I want to avoid the situation that directory A and its content is uploaded, but my seperate `file D` is not due to a shutdown during `aws s3 sync`. Or that directory A is partially synced.

**What is the most easiest solution to ensure dir/fileset {A,B,C,D} on S3 is always pointing to the current state or is always pointing to the previous state?**

So i have some questions:

- Is there a way to make `aws s3 sync` **automic**, so if a shutdown happens during an S3 sync, all files on S3 remains in the state as before the sync.
- Is `aws s3 sync` atomic per file? E.g. assume it is uploading file B, and this sync process gets killed. Is file B on S3 now (a) potentially corrupt or (b) does it contains the old state?
- Are there other possibilities: e.g. AWS always let finish a sync prior to termination, and new sync requests are not accepted if a instance is terminating.

If the first option is not possible, but the second is, then the option is to TAR all files, and sync that. However this add some extra layer of complexity because when I start a new instance and download from S3 I need to play forward the TAR over the filesystem.

If all this does not help is it possible (and yes how) to:

- Replicate (atomicly) S3 my root directory E (which contains {A,B,C,D} ) to Etmp
- Run the sync
- Remove Etmp (atomicly)

Then I can do at instance startup:

- If Etmp exist consider this as the stable state. Replace E by Etmp.

If this is not possible via the CLI tools, does e.g. the **Java S3 SDK** provide services to 'commit'  multiple fileuploads? If so how, because then I write my custom file syncer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can monitor for Spot Termination Notifications and this gives me 2 minutes to sync data.